# Call a javascript file from a Java Bean

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

I have 3 files :

- index.xhtml : I used JSF, to make a 2 fields form (x : int, y : int) with a submission button.
- map.js : contains a Js function.
- MbZoomtoXy.java : That call the previous Js function.

What I try to do is when I enter x and y in the form. The submission button should give me the "alert" of x+y.

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

       <h:form id="form">

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel for="x-coor" value="X : " />
            <p:inputText id="x-coor" value="#{MbZoomtoXy.x}" required="true"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="y-coor" value="Y : " />
            <p:inputText id="y-coor" value="#{MbZoomtoXy.y}" required="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{MbZoomtoXy.save}"/>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**map.js**

```
function zoomToXy(x,y){
    var s = x + y;
    alert("x+y = "+s);  
}
```

**MbZoomtoXy.java**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MbZoomtoXy {

    private MbZoomtoXy() {
        }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

       int x,y;

    public MbZoomtoXy(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

     //Here I don t know how to call zoomToXy(x,y) function of map.js
    public void save(){
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        requestContext.execute("...");

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add the click handler to the client code, you can't (in a practical way) call a JavaScript function this way from Java. give the button an ID and use something like jQuery to add a click handler. You'll possibly need to do some modification in your JSF file to prevent it from POSTing back into Java immediately (or use preventDefault on the click event).

Comment: As @JeffWatkins says, you already have the input values at client side. So try to grab them and display them into an alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need put `map.js` in `src/main/webapp/resources/js/map.js`, and include in `index.html`

**index.html**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="map.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <p:outputLabel for="x-coor" value="X : " />
            <p:inputText id="x-coor" value="#{MbZoomtoXy.x}" required="true"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="y-coor" value="Y : " />
            <p:inputText id="y-coor" value="#{MbZoomtoXy.y}" required="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{MbZoomtoXy.save}"/>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**MbZoomtoXy.java**

```
package com.test;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


@ManagedBean(name = "MbZoomtoXy")
@SessionScoped
public class MbZoomtoXy implements Serializable {

    public MbZoomtoXy() {
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    int x,y;

    public MbZoomtoXy(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    //Here I don t know how to call zoomToXy(x,y) function of map.js
    public void save(){
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.execute(String.format("zoomToXy(%1$d, %2$d)", x, y));
    }
}
```